# Loading items from array in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I would llike tot test the performance of three frontend frameworks. AngularJS Angular 2 and EmberJS.

Currently I am trying to load 1000 objects from a number array to test the performance. I have encountered dificulties with loading the items from the array into a html list when loading the page.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <input type="button" value="load items">
 <ul>
 <li  (load)="ngOnInit() "*ngFor="let number of numberArray">
 <span class="badge">{{number}}</span> 
 <li>
 </ul>`
})




export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    var numberArray: Array<number> = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      numberArray.push(i);
    }
    console.log(numberArray);
  }

};
```

To clarify my problem:
I want to load the 1000 object from my array when I load the page
I look forward to your answer

Comment: You will have to expose the array to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind `numberArray` to `AppComponent` class, so that it gets exposed to html.

So change `var numberArray: Array<number> = [];` to `numberArray: Array<number> = [];` ouside `ngOnInit()` function and then access via `this`

Do it like :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
numberArray: Array<number> = [];
  ngOnInit(): void {    
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      this.numberArray.push(i);
    }
    console.log(numberArray);
  }    
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

simply use your required html code inside a `*ngIf` as follows

```
<div *ngIf="numberArray.length > 0">
<input type="button" value="load items">
 <ul>
 <li  (load)="ngOnInit() "*ngFor="let number of numberArray">
 <span class="badge">{{number}}</span> 
 <li>
 </ul>
<div>
```

**define `numberArray` variable as global variable**